# java datatype for Oracle's RAW

Tags: java, oracle

I having a oracle procedure which accepts `RAW` datatype as input. While referring [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/basic3.htm), I got I have to use `byte[]`. But my input value is something that doesn't fits in `byte[]`. Sample input data is `2F2F283C4267A67DE0536568ED0A1073`. Can someone help how to pass this input data from java side to oracle procedure.

Comment: Are you aware that `RAW` is deprecated? Why don't you use a `BLOB`?

Comment: Ok, I am not Oracle expert, but thanks, I will convey this to DB team.

Comment: And unless you're storing 2GB objects, everything will fit in a byte array.

Comment: @chrylis, u mean to say there is no need for RAW  data-type ahh?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you cite a reference? I could find no reference that says `RAW` is deprecated. Are there any advantages to using `BLOB` over `RAW` other than the unbounded nature of `BLOB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. I understand the input I having in my hand is a hex representation so I just convert that to byte array, that did the trick.

```
DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("2F2F283C4267A67DE0536568ED0A1073")
```

Answer (score 2):

Natural choice for `RAW` datatype is `byte[] (Byte[])`. It will always fit since `RAW` can hold up to 2000 bytes. It is not that much.
Today `RAW` is sometimes is used for UUIDs which have 16B only. It is more efficient than storing them as VARCHAR2(32). Maybe this is also your reason.

The datatype which was deprecated is `LONG RAW`. This one can have up to 2GB.